# two almost same function into one?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I've got two function. They are doing the same thing actually. Getting data from database results by fieldNameArray into array of Int or Double.. how can i merge these two functions into one ? is that possible ? only difference is fields type and so return type..

```
func fieldsToInt ( fieldNameArray : [String] ) -> [Int] {
   var returnArray = [Int]()
   for fNA in fieldNameArray {
      let n = Int ( results.int(forColumn: fNA) )
      returnArray.append( n )
    }
   return returnArray;
}

func fieldsToDouble ( fieldNameArray : [String] ) -> [Double] {
   var returnArray = [Double]()
   for fNA in fieldNameArray {
   let n = Double ( results.int(forColumn: fNA) )
      returnArray.append( n )
   }
   return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try generics, like

```
func fieldsToNumber<T> ( fieldNameArray : [String] ) -> [T] {
   var returnArray = [T]()
   for fNA in fieldNameArray {
   let n = T ( results.int(forColumn: fNA) )
      returnArray.append( n )
   }
   return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, you should use [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html), in particular you need a generic function.

The code that solves your problem would roughly look like this:

```swift
// This is a struct to mock the code you didn't post
struct Results {

    func int(forColumn: String) -> Int16 {
        return 1
    }
}

let results = Results()

protocol DatabaseElementRepresentable {

    init?(_ databaseValue: Int16)
}

func fields<Element: DatabaseElementRepresentable>(fieldNameArray : [String]) -> [Element] {
    var returnArray = [Element]()
    for fNA in fieldNameArray {
        if let n = Element(results.int(forColumn: fNA)) {
            returnArray.append(n)
        }
    }
    return returnArray
}

extension Int: DatabaseElementRepresentable { }
extension Double: DatabaseElementRepresentable { }

let ints: [Int] = fields(fieldNameArray: ["test"])
let doubles: [Double] = fields(fieldNameArray: ["test"])
```

Please, change `Int16` with the value the function `int(forColumn:` returns

Comment: results.int(forColumn: fNA) as? Element   line gives error,  Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'T?' conform to 'BinaryInteger'  and besides, results.int or results.double ? how to know which one to chose ?

Comment: The first error is hard to understand without knowing the type the function `int(forColumn:` returns, however I've updated the snipped adding also an example of the usage (the last two lines)